# How can i add css code to a php file using <style> tags, current approach not working.

Tags: php, html, css

I'll include a basic example code; im trying to understand how to add css editing to a php file - within the file. Currently when the webpage opens from the server the editing is not applying.

lets say I want the variable myBirthday in the following code to increase in size and change colour to red, how do i fix this code?

```
<head>
   <title>
       countdown
   </title>
      <style type=”text/css”>
        #myBirthday
        {
          font-size: 100;
          color: #FF0000;
        }
      </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>
      My birthday.
    </h1>
    <?php
        $myBirthday = "10th October 1997";
        echo "Tell you a secret, my birthday is " . $myBirthday . <br> "Today is " .date('d-m-y') . ". <br>";
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: You did not assign the id `myBirthday` to any element. Please do this and see if it works.

Comment: You don't add CSS to a PHP file, you add it to HTML

Comment: change the `echo` to `echo '<p id="myBirthday">...</p>';` You need to assign the `#myBirthday` ID to an element on the page with your birthday text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enclosed the `myBirthday` variable within a `span` which I gave the ID `myBrirthday` in order to style it with the CSS code you provided

```
<body>
    <h1>
      My birthday.
    </h1>
    <?php
        $myBirthday = "10th October 1997";
        echo "Tell you a secret, my birthday is <span id=\"myBirthday\">" . $myBirthday ."</span> <br> Today is " .date('d-m-y') . ". <br>";
    ?>
</body>
```

Also note that double quotes must be escaped when inside the "echo" statement.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: you got a point @JayBlanchard and I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Even using this code, there is still no css editing after uploading to server and refreshing link.

Comment: i.e. the variable 'myBirthday' is not increased in size or changed in colour as the css code should have made it do.

Comment: hmm, kinda confused myself too... I looked at it and seems ok... /)

Comment: Oh, come on... Your css was also wrong... Try: font-size:100px @JohnSmith (Check this link for font-size property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Comment: @JohnSmith, Copy and paste the entire "echo" line, because in your question it is also written with a mistake.